# Laravel query database with results from previous query

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel am trying to query a database with the results of a previous query. My current code:

```
$firstResults = Model1:all()->sortByDesc('id')->take(1)->toArray();
$secondResults = Model2:all()->where('hash',$firstResults["hash"])->toArray();
```

The first query works fine. I want to use the results of the first query to search the second table where 'hash' is equal to the 'hash' value from the results of the first query. I got an error of Undefined index: hash when I ran the above code.

I tried the following to see the results of the first query:

```
$firstResults = Model1:all()->sortByDesc('id')->take(1)->toArray();
var_dump($firstResults);
die();
$secondResults = Model2:all()->where('hash',$firstResults["hash"])->toArray();
```

The results seem to be an array with an array inside it:

array(1) { [12]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> int(92) ["hash"]=> string(64) "0ae34d.......

every time I refresh, the index increases by one:

array(1) { [13]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> int(92) ["hash"]=> string(64) "0ae34d.......

array(1) { [14]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> int(92) ["hash"]=> string(64) "0ae34d.......

array(1) { [15]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> int(92) ["hash"]=> string(64) "0ae34d.......

Not sure why this is happening, and this is preventing me from trying $firstResults[12]["hash"]

Comment: Just an FYI, your code is not querying the database, in both examples you actually fetching all of the results from the database and the filtering down the collection. It would also be worth setting up a relationship between `Model1` and `Model2` so that you simply do something like: `Model1::with('model2')->latest()->first();`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a different approach similar to yours.

```
$firstResults = Model1:latest('id')->first()->toArray();
```

Then simply:

```
$secondResults = Model2:where('hash',$firstResults['hash'])->get()->toArray();
```

Also collections are more "powerful" to use and way more flexible than arrays. Sometimes of course you need to cast them to arrays but i suggest you learn to work with collections as well.

Furthermore the `$secondResults` i modified it in a way that you actually query the table and not the collection that comes from `all()`. In your code what you were doing is retrieving all the table records and then filter them but that is not how a query should work and of course it will be heavy as records grow more and more.

As discussed in the comments since you want to use arrays all the outputs are casted into arrays that you can use.

The firstResult will return a single dimensional array and the secondResult a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it creates issues in the view file. When I @foreach $firstResults and try {{$row['number_pages']}} I get an error exception. "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Comment: ok then you can cast it to array if you use it in other parts of the code. I modified my code. Now your `$firstResults` is a single dimensional array that you can use. Don't see why you loop over it though since even in your example you used `take(1)`

Comment: The updated code has the same error as with my originally stated problem.  Cast it to array later? after $secondResults = ....?

Comment: How can this be done later?

Comment: I updated my answer so  that you understand what was wrong with what you were trying to do. I elaborate a lot in my answer but i can not see your full code and i focus on answering your specific question in the most optimized way.